# How to make color (red) look like different color (blue) on windows 10 monitor

Tags: display, colors, color-profiles

I have an Nvidia graphics card. I'm wondering how I would go on changing the color red to blue on my windows 10 monitor. The best way I could draw a comparison to what I'm trying to do is like how you can edit a photo in photoshop to color replace certain colors.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? It looks like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)